# How can I select the child of a sibling element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My accordion keeps filling up the space of my `div` bigger and smaller based on it opening and closing. I want to wrap a `div` around it and set it to the height of the accordion expanded to prevent this behavior. Trouble is my js is dependent on selecting `this.nextSibling` and that breaks everything.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("review-button");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
    } 
  }
}
```

It must be using "`this`" within scope because there are multiple accordions.
My original thought was to do something like...

```
this.nextElementSibling.children[0];
```

but that didn't work.

how do I wrap the current content in a `div` with a set height, while still keeping the accordion functionality?

```
<!--accordion 1-->     
<button class="review-button"  data-target="#demo{{ gameIndex }}">
     <span class="review-button-chevron fa fa-angle-down"></span>       
      Our Reviews
     </button>

<!-- Slide out -->
<div class="quote-machine-container">
    <div id="demo{{ gameIndex }}" class=" quote-machine"></div>
</div>

<!--accordion 2-->
 <button class="review-button"  data-target="#demo{{ gameIndex }}">
     <span class="review-button-chevron fa fa-angle-down"></span>       
      Our Reviews
     </button>

<!-- Slide out -->
<div class="quote-machine-container">
    <div id="demo{{ gameIndex }}" class=" quote-machine"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML snippet.

Comment: Are you sure in the onclick function this == acc[I]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Placed each `<header>` and `<div>` in it's own `<section>`
2. Wrapped everything in `<main>` and added an `eventListener()` to it. Any clicks to it will be delegated to the header that was clicked (`e.target`.)
3. The event handler (`acc()`) will:

   - determine what is `e.target` (clicked node) by comparing it to the `e.currentTarget` (the node being captured at the moment.)
   - Once established, `e.target` will lose or gain the `.active` class.
   - In order to eliminate the limiting property of `nextElementSibling`, we replace that functionality with a simple CSS ruleset: `.active + .x-panel` which is basically the same as `nextElementSibling`.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var main = document.getElementById("x-main");

main.addEventListener('click', acc, false);

function acc(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    tgt.classList.toggle("active");
  }
}
```

```css
.x-section {
  height: 100px;
}
.x-header {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px outset grey;
  height: 30px;
}
.x-panel {
  border: 3px inset black;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
}
.active + .x-panel {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in .1s, opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<main id='x-main'>
  <section class='x-section'>
    <header class='x-header'>HEADER</header>
    <div class='x-panel'>
      CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class='x-section'>
    <header class='x-header'>HEADER</header>
    <div class='x-panel'>
      CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class='x-section'>
    <header class='x-header'>HEADER</header>
    <div class='x-panel'>
      CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: I should be able to figure it out from here, you rock

Comment: Excellent, sir. Happy coding.